# MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter creates extra/duplicate xml elements during marshalling

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, marshalling, xjc

i am using xjc to create jaxb binding classes from an xsd... and using MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter to convert the objects to xml.. but what i am seeing is, when i have a list in the binding file, the converter creates a duplicate xml element..

XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="orderSubmitType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="orderId" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="giftCards" type="giftCards"/>

    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="giftCards">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="giftCard" type="giftCard"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="10"/>
    </xs:sequence>

</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="giftCard">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="cardNumber" type="xs:string" /> 
        <xs:element name="pinNumber" type="xs:string" /> 
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

JAVA:

public class TestRestTemplateConfiguration {

```
public static RestTemplate getTestClientRestTemplate() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new TestClientResponseErrorHandler());
        ClientHttpRequestInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new TestClientLoggingInterceptor();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(loggingInterceptor));
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));
       MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter jacksonXmlConverter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(jacksonConverter,jacksonXmlConverter));
        INSTANCE = restTemplate;
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

}

final xml that is created is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderSubmitType>
   <orderId>111111</orderId>
   <giftCards>
      <giftCard>
         <giftCard>
            <cardNumber>123456790</cardNumber>
            <pinNumber>1111</pinNumber>
         </giftCard>
      </giftCard>
   </giftCards>
</OrderSubmitType>
```

as you can see... there is a extra 
`<giftcard></giftcard>` elements...

can anyone tell me what is the mistake that i am doing...

thanks...